# C how can i resolve assignment from incompatible pointer type when using struct* = struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trawled these forums a looking for a solution to the problem but i could not seem to located one for my specific solution.

The problem i am having is, i want to implement a linked list aspect but i am not concerned about the head of the list, i just need to know the order to the structures.

The general idea is that:

struct 1 -> struct 2-> struct n->struct n+1

so i can then go:

struct n -> struct n-1 ........

i have defined my header as so:

```
 typedef struct {

        unsigned int value;
        struct item* prev;


    } item;
```

I read in muliple item values from a simple file which is basically:

```
23
421
12
234
etc ...
```

I load the items into an area of malloc'd memory large enough and when i read them in from the file i do this:

```
item* items;
items = malloc(no_of_lines * sizeof(item));

 for (i = 0; i < no_of_lines; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &item[i] != EOF) {
      }
    }
```

But when i try to assign the previous to an item:

```
for (i = 0; i < no_of_lines; i++){
   if(i != 0){
      item[i].prev = item[i-1];
      }
 }
```

I get this error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct item *’ from type ‘item’
```

I have tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < no_of_lines; i++){
       if(i != 0){
          item[i].prev = &item[i-1];
          }
     }
```

and

```
for (i = 0; i < no_of_lines; i++){
           if(i != 0){
              item[i].prev = (item *)&item[i-1];
              }
         }
```

both produce the warning:

```
assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `items = malloc(no_of_lines * sizeof *items);` for a start ...

Comment: Be careful with `items` vs `item`. One is an array; the other is a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this definition:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int value;
    struct item* prev;  /* <---- here */
} item;
```

That line **is not** declaring a pointer to this struct, because the name `item` is not introduced until the end of the full declaration. This is actually a nameless struct, with an alias named `item`. Somewhere you have another, maybe similar, struct that is named `item`:

```
struct item {
     //unknown contents (for me)
};
```

The difference is that this type is named `struct item` while the original one is just `item`, without the `struct` keyword.

If they are not the same, you should name them differently, to avoid confusion. And if they are actually the same, you should remove one of the declarations. Note that you can declare the named struct and an alias at the same time, and then they both will refer to the same type:

```
typedef struct item {
    unsigned int value;
    struct item* prev;
} item;
```

Or you can do it in separated declarations, it's just the same;

```
struct item {
    unsigned int value;
    struct item* prev;
};
typedef struct item item;
```

Other than that, the assignment is with the `&` operator:

```
items[i].prev = &items[i-1];
```

Comment: i see, our teacher told us to use that format i did ask why do some people write typedef struct name{}name; and he said dont worry about it.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `item[i]->prev = &item[i-1];` since we're dereferencing a pointer, not a static instance of the struct..

Comment: @chrisedwards: Well, type `typedef struct {...} name;` idiom is a very bad idea, IMO. The problem is that it declares the struct _without_ a name, and then an alias. There are problems with that: for example, many debuggers will not show the typedef names properly. My advice would be: if you want a struct with a name, do a struct with a name: `struct name {...};`.

Comment: @stellarhopper: No, `item` is a pointer (or `items`, some typo out there), but `item[i]` is a struct. Thus, `item[i].prev` accesses the member.

Comment: @rodrigo: wrong: `item` is a typedef name. `items` is the name of a pointer variable (pointing to XXX items of size item) Extra confusing, since the OP edited the post within the grace period.

Comment: @chrisedwards: And the problem remains that you probably have several different declarations with the name `item`.

Comment: i admit after being told how my code was poorly written in terms of names and such, i will tidy it up promptly. thanks.

Comment: @chrisedwards: A last suggestion: many people like to name the types with the first letter uppercase and the variables all lowercase, so `Item` will be a type and `item` a variable. No more confusions!

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks, im still learning been doing C about 2 months so sorry if im horrible and it!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem maybe be the typedef. Just remove the keyword.

```
typedef struct {

        unsigned int value;
        struct item* prev;


    } item;
```

This means declare a type called 'item'.

As a general rule: give everything a unique name. You have a 'struct item' and typedef 'item' and 'item = malloc'. Confusing.